# How can I set the System Time in Java?

Tags: java, systemtime

Is it possible to change the System Time in Java?

It should run under Windows and Linux. I've tried it with the `Runtime` Class in but there is a problem with the permissions.

This is my code:

```
String cmd="date -s \""+datetime.format(ntp_obj.getDest_Time())+"\"";
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
} catch (IOException e1) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e1.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(cmd);
```

The output of `cmd` is:

```
date -s "06/01/2011 17:59:01"
```

But the System time is the same as before.

I will set the time because I am writing an NTP-Client and there I get the time from a NTP-Server and will set it.

Comment: Why do you need to set the System time?

Comment: Also include the current *relevant* code and error/problem's encountered (e.g. what was "wrong" with the permissions?)

Comment: @SSZero Because the System time is incorrect / not accurate?

Comment: You need a separate time command on Windows. Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C time " + strTimeToSet); // hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Java doesn't have an API to do this.

Most system commands to do it require admin rights, so `Runtime` can't help unless you run the whole process as administrator/root or you use `runas`/`sudo`.

Depending on what you need, you can replace `System.currentTimeMillis()`. There are two approaches to this:

1. Replace all calls to `System.currentTimeMillis()` with a call to a static method of your own which you can replace:

   ```
   public class SysTime {
       public static SysTime INSTANCE = new SysTime();

       public long now() {
           return System.currentTimeMillis();
       }
   }
   ```

   For tests, you can overwrite INSTANCE with something that returns other times. Add more methods to create `Date` and similar objects.
2. If not all code is under your control, install a `ClassLoader` which returns a different implementation for `System`. This is more simple than you'd think:

   ```
   @Override
   public Class<?> loadClass( String name, boolean resolve ) {
       if ( "java.lang.System".equals( name ) ) {
           return SystemWithDifferentTime.class;
       }

       return super.loadClass( name, resolve );
   }
   ```

Comment: Will installing a class loader with a `java.lang.*` name always work?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing magic about `java.lang` as far as classloading is concerned. There *should* be nothing magic about it as far as JIT and VM are concerned - if you replace `String.class` with something else, this should work since the class is loaded like anything else.

Comment: I'm testing approach no. 2 and getting: java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.lang so I think there actually is something "magic" about java.lang.

Comment: @BoneGoat: No, there isn't. But you have a `SecurityManager` installed and then, things like that aren't possible anymore. Use `joda-time` instead.

Answer (score 25):

One way would be using native commands.

for Windows, two commands (date and time) are required:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C date " + strDateToSet); // dd-MM-yy
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C time " + strTimeToSet); // hh:mm:ss
```

for linux, a single command handles both date and time:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("date -s " + strDateTimeToSet); // MMddhhmm[[yy]yy]
```

**Update after 9 year**

This is not a good way to set the time of system instead of that use `java.util.Clock` to get the current time and provide mock implementation wherever needed to fake out the time.

Comment: @Pacerier Not sure if there is different command/util in Mac, you can try it out on Mac's terminal

Comment: @JigarJoshi problem is I don't have a Mac

Comment: (On Windows) btw date only changes the date, we'd also need to execute the command time to change the system time.

Comment: @msanjay look for command to set time, I guess date should do it

Comment: As `exec()` forks a new process for each call, I'd recommend to concat the two windows calls like so: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C date " + strDateToSet + "& time " + strTimeToSet);`

Comment: Other solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43615487/best-way-to-set-date-and-time-on-windows-machine-by-java-application/43708379#43708379

Comment: Is there any way to do it in a mac?

Comment: @JigarJoshi please check the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708597/custom-dynamic-clock-in-java

Comment: Is it really month-day-hour-minute-year? Who came up with that date format?

Answer (score 4):

You can only set the system time by running a command line tool as root or Adminstrator.  The command are different but you can check the OS first and run the appropriate command for that OS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JNI` for setting the system time. This would work on Windows. You need to know `JNI` and `C`.

This is the JNI function, the prototype will be generated by the `javah` utility

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_TimeSetter_setSystemTime
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jshort hour, jshort minutes) {

    SYSTEMTIME st;
    GetLocalTime(&st);  
    st.wHour = hour;      
    st.wMinute = minutes;  
    SetLocalTime(&st);   
}
```

The Java JNI wrapper would be

```
class TimeSetter {

    public native void setSystemTime( short hour, short minutes);

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("TimeSetter");
    }
}
```

And finally, to use it

```
public class JNITimeSetter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        short hour = 8;
        short minutes = 30;

        // Set the system at 8h 30m

        TimeSetter ts = new TimeSetter();
        ts.setSystemTime(hour, minutes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are cases where the process does not run with admin rights, but it still has the permissions to set the system time. It is possible to use [Java Native Access](https://github.com/twall/jna%20Java%20Native%20Access%20(JNA)) to change the system time and have all the required sources in Java (simpler compared with JNI).

```
package github.jna;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase.SYSTEMTIME;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

/**
 * Provides access to the Windows SetSystemTime native API call.
 * This class is based on examples found in
 * <a href="https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md">JNA Getting Started</a>
 */
public class WindowsSetSystemTime {

    /**
     * Kernel32 DLL Interface.
     * kernel32.dll uses the __stdcall calling convention (check the function 
     * declaration for "WINAPI" or "PASCAL"), so extend StdCallLibrary
     * Most C libraries will just extend com.sun.jna.Library,
     */
    public interface Kernel32 extends StdCallLibrary {

        boolean SetLocalTime(SYSTEMTIME st);

        Kernel32 instance = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("kernel32.dll", Kernel32.class);

    }

    public boolean SetLocalTime(SYSTEMTIME st) {
        return Kernel32.instance.SetLocalTime(st);
    }

    public boolean SetLocalTime(short wYear, short wMonth, short wDay, short wHour, short wMinute, short wSecond) {
        SYSTEMTIME st = new SYSTEMTIME();
        st.wYear = wYear;
        st.wMonth = wMonth;
        st.wDay = wDay;
        st.wHour = wHour;
        st.wMinute = wMinute;
        st.wSecond = wSecond;
        return SetLocalTime(st);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package myTestProject;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class LocalTimeChangeTest {

    private static DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String value = "2014-12-12 00:26:14";
            Date date = dateFormat.parse(value);
            value = dateFormat.format(date);
            final Process dateProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c date "+value.substring(0, value.lastIndexOf(' ')));
            dateProcess.waitFor();
            dateProcess.exitValue();
            final Process timeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c time "+value.substring(value.lastIndexOf(' ')+1));
            timeProcess.waitFor();
            timeProcess.exitValue();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Run this code under windows administrator model.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.test;

public class Exec {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String[] cmd = {"/bin/bash","-c","echo yourPassword | sudo -S date --set='2017-05-13 21:59:10'"};
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the date or add the date in current date using below code. It is working perfectly in windows:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");    
String strExpectedDate = s.format(new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("cmd /C date " + strExpectedDate);
```

In above code I have added 1 day to current date, You can pass any date for strExpectedDate and this will only work on windows

Answer (score 0):

I did it with shortcuts. Shortcut has link to `cmd` with commands, changing time or synchronize time with server time. As changing system settings shortcut should be called with admin permission there is a method automatically setting shortcut flag `Run as administrator`. To be sure that synchronization was succesfull there is a method `safeSynchronize` changing time to fake time and only after that ask the server time. For me it works perfectly.

```
package system;

import mslinks.ShellLink;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

public class TimeSynchronizer {

    Random random = new Random();

    private int WAIT_LAG = 1000;

    private DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
    private DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    public void synchronize() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        File file = getFile();
        makeShortcut(file, "/c net start w32time");
        callShortcut(file);
        makeShortcut(file, "/c w32tm /resync");
        callShortcut(file);
        if (file.exists()) file.delete();
    }

    public void safeSynchronize() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        int minute = rightNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        boolean isForward = minute < 30;
        Date date = DateUtils.addMinutes(Date.from(Instant.now()), 10 * (isForward ? 1 : -1));

        setTime(date);
        synchronize();
    }

    public void setTime(Date date) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        setTime(date, false);
    }

    public void setTime(Date date, boolean withDate) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        File file = getFile();
        if (withDate) {
            makeShortcut(file, "/c date " + dateFormat.format(date));
            callShortcut(file);
        }
        makeShortcut(file, "/c time " + timeFormat.format(date));
        callShortcut(file);
        if (file.exists()) file.delete();
    }

    private void callShortcut(File file) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            getSystem32Path() + "\\cmd.exe /c start /wait \"\" \"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\""
        );
        process.waitFor();
        process.exitValue();
    }

    private String getSystem32Path() {
        return System.getenv("SystemRoot") + "\\system32";
    }

    private File getFile() {
        return new File(random.nextInt() + "shortcut.lnk");
    }

    private void makeShortcut(File file, String command) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String system32Path = getSystem32Path();
        ShellLink s = new ShellLink();
        s.setTarget(system32Path + "\\cmd.exe");
        s.setCMDArgs(command);
        s.saveTo(file.getAbsolutePath());
        Thread.sleep(WAIT_LAG);

        setRunAsAdmin(file);
    }

    private void setRunAsAdmin(File file) throws IOException {
        byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
        fileContent[21] = (char)32;
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, fileContent);
    }
}
```