# How to know user executing the class has rights to change system time?

Tags: java

I need to know using Java if the user that executes the Java class has the required permission to change the system time.

I just need a boolean returning method.

Comment: You can't change the system time in Java so I suspect there is no standard way to check for permission to do this either.  How do you give your user's permissions currently?

Comment: Why there is need of checking that permission? Besides, you can check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203857/how-can-i-set-the-system-time-in-java) for more details.

Comment: It seems to me, that in any case solution will depend on used OS

Comment: We currently have to allow the user to change the system time via a dialog (it's part of the requirements) and we do it usgin Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command). But if the user doesn't have rights to do it, then the time doesn't change. So I would like to assert if the user has the rights to show a popup alerting the user so he can call support or something like that.

Comment: We change the command depending on the OS in which the app is running.

Comment: Why don't you *try* and change the time, then if its not changed raise a pop up?

Comment: I already do that check, but I'd prefer to assert beforehand whether the user will be able to perform said action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not trivial.

On Unix-based systems, you can check whether the current user has the capability `CAP_SYS_TIME` but there is no standard way to check this from Java.

On Windows, they will need admin rights but I don't know which permission exactly. Like on Unix, there is no Java API that you could use to check.

Maybe an external script/binary could do the check. You could then use `ProcessBuilder` to execute this tool.

Comment: I was afraid that this was the only choice, so I think we'll end using this aproach. Thank you all.