# Fake system clock on certain date

Tags: java, testing

I need to set the system clock on certain date in my tests. This way I must simulate a behavior happening that date under a test. I found this article http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=234

But it does not give you much hint how to set the fake system clock e.g. 2.5.2013.

Please help me.

Comment: What is the challenge - setting the time, or working out what Unix time is equivalent to time and date in human readable format?

Comment: I think you should check this earlier [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203857/how-can-i-set-the-system-time-in-java).

Comment: Setting the date so that the tests kind of "thinks" its running on certain date.

Comment: There's no way, in any system-independent fashion, to "fake" the system clock.  It may be possible on some JVMs, but the technique would not be portable.  You have to change the time as reported by the OS -- change your hardware clock.

Comment: You might want to take a look at these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001671/override-java-system-currenttimemillis and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203857/how-can-i-set-the-system-time-in-java .

Comment: Show us the code you want to test and what you've tried. Perhaps you should look into mocking frameworks?.

Comment: Im not sure if the code gives any additional information? The scenario is that my application uses database and shows certain database data on certain dates. These information varitions should be tested with selenium tests.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you need to manipulate time for your tests and not really change the system clock... consider using [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net), this has the functionality baked in, e.g.:

```
// always return the same time when querying current time
DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(millis);

// then test 
assert new DateTime().getMillis() == millis;

// reset time
DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisSystem()
```

You'll have to weigh up the trade off between using Joda-Time and implementing a solution yourself though!

Answer (score 0):

In general is manipulating the system datetime isn't a good practice, i still remember each time when i ran the unittests how my outlook got crazy and how all kind of reminders from the past popped up.

You can create a static class which returns the datetime depending on the environment, so in the test Env. it will allow setting datetime which you can access while on real running it will return the system date/time.

Answer (score 0):

> But it does not give you much hint how to set the fake system clock e.g. 2.5.2013.

It does. I suppose you followed the steps and replaced all the calls to system time with interface (`TimeSource` for example). If you need to simulate specific date you can use the following implementation in your test classes:

```
public final class TestTimeSrc implements TimeSource {

  public long currentTimeMillis() {
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.set(2013, 4, 2);
     return calendar.getTime().getTime();
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but does this really simulate the  SYSTEM clock, not just returning certain dates in application?

Comment: @mjgirl That's the whole point. Create an intermediate class that will serve system time in production code. Then, when you need to test particular date values you can create fake intermediate class and don't bother simulating system clock.