# Determine date on Maven profile

Tags: java, maven, testing

As a futher question to this: [Fake system clock on certain date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200705/fake-system-clock-on-certain-date)

Is it possible to set certain date on Maven profile? After all, I use testing profile which determines the usage of test database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Maven profile, you could pass in a date-time as a system property via Surefire:

```
...
<profile>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <testDateTime>2013-01-01T00:00:00.000Z</testDateTime>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
...
```

And then use it in your tests like so:

```
final String dateTime = System.getProperty("testDateTime");
// parse date-time etc...
```

Does that help?

Comment: assuming that you can also set the date from test, that's great!