# How programmatically change time and date at linux (ubuntu) by Java?

Tags: java, linux, datetime, ubuntu

Anybody know how programmatically change system time and date at linux (ubuntu) by Java ?
I'm two days looking for decision for this but not yet find...
I tried use Date(), SimpleDateFormat() and Calendar but it doesn't works...
Anybody help me?
Thanks:)

Comment: it doesn't works. ??? what not working ??

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203857/how-can-i-set-the-system-time-in-java

Comment: You could not find anything because the standard library does not have a method to change system time/date. I bet you will need JNI.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: I need change and Set new system Date. For example, i used SimpleDateFormat class - I cganged time, take Print and watch that. But i can't set that new time like system time...