# Java-Fake system clock in launch

Tags: java, date

For a workaround , I need to change the system clock for a certain java program without touching the code in order to get for :

```
calendar.getinstance().get(calendar.year) = 2013
```

is it possible just with setting a variable through launch configuration?

Thanks

EDIT :Sorry , i want to simulate the current year as 2013

Comment: This may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203857/how-can-i-set-the-system-time-in-java

Comment: You could temporarily mock the Calendar class to return what you need then unmock it.

Comment: Thanks,but i can't change or add code , so im wondering if can do it with system or user properties.

Comment: @bazic Then you have to change the system date / time. You need admin rights for this.

Comment: @Moritz Petersen : There are others java programs in the same server

Comment: @bazic If you are trying to fake the current date on a production environment, you should definitively rethink your setup. You should have a test environment for these cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, without admin rights it is not possible to set the system clock on OS level. This would also affect all software running on the machine. But you want to change the clock just for one program. So when you deny this option of setting the system clock then it follows that any kind of code change is necessary (what you don't want). You cannot fake the system time just by configuration properties without any code change.

Second, the idea of mocking java.util.Date (writing a subclass) might work for you, although it requires code change. See this interesting [link](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2009/12/06/testing-times-in-java) using instrumentation.

Third, the new JSR-310 coming in Java 8 has a special class `java.time.Clock` which allows to be injected in existing code and can simulate a fake clock. The advantage of this solution is: Once you have prepared your program this way then you can indeed change the clock later just by configuration. But at least once you need an initial code change.

Comment: Related to this, if the OP was using [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (the precursor to JSR310, essentially), there's a similar set of functions allowing you to change the clock.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Indeed, JodaTime offers the interface `org.joda.time.DateTimeUtils.MillisProvider`. I regret that JSR-310-clock is an abstract class, not an interface. Stephen Colebourne made recently the statement that it is too late to change this for Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux you can try to fake the time with a library: http://archive09.linux.com/feature/147801 .

I never tried this and I don't know if this works with Java.