# How to set a time zone in a Java application on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, datetime, time, datepicker

I'm trying to add a function to an application that allows the user to select a time zone for the app.

My application runs on Windows and uses time in all its functions (storing data, displaying it, deleting it etcetera): so time is very important here.

I just want the user to be able to select the time zone to use within the application itself - i.e. without having to close the application and change it in Windows settings.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203857/how-can-i-set-the-system-time-in-java) - looks like a similar question. From that question (and accepted answer), apparently changing system time is NOT possible thorough Java Runtime unless you run the whole process with Admin/Sudo access.

Comment: I believe the Rolling Stones have a [song](http://youtu.be/XG5GOH2CO1k) about this.

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to set the actual _operating system_ time zone from a Java application, or just select _a_ time zone for use only within the application?

Comment: Yes, I want the user to set the actual operating system time zone from java application.