# Setting milliseconds of System time with java

Tags: java, windows, time, command-line, process

Would it be possible to set system time with milliseconds component on Windows OS using Java?
I am trying to synchronize clocks between couple of computers but the OS API seems to offer only set time in format: **HH:MM:SS**.

This is what i tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {


    String time="10:00:20"; // this works

    String timeWithMiliseconds = "10:00:20.100"; // this doesn't change time at all

    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    rt.exec("cmd /C time " + time);


}
```

I am wondering how do NTP clients work if it's not possible to set milliseconds component ?

One way to deal with this issue could be to calculate time in milliseconds when server should reach next second, and sleep for that time. Is there a better, more direct way to achieve this ?

Comment: Because they don't use the console command to set the time; they probably use the [SetSystemTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, which (like any other Windows function) you can't easily access from Java.

Comment: Thank you for comment. So it wouldn't be possible to call that function with ProcessBuilder/Runtime, have to use JNI ?

Comment: Why can't you just use an NTP client directly?

Comment: It's just an assignment i am working on and am not allowed to do so.

Comment: To call methods that are not part of Java (but C ish) you'll have to use JNI http://stackoverflow.com/a/17035731/995891 (or [jna](http://blog.caplin.com/2014/12/01/jnajni/)). Or maybe you could start a script / custom exe via `Runtime` that allows to set time in ms precision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by immibis you could use the Windows function `SetSystemTime` to set the time.

Find below a snippet which call the Windows function using [JNA 4.2](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna.git)

```
Kernel32 kernel = Kernel32.INSTANCE;
WinBase.SYSTEMTIME newTime = new WinBase.SYSTEMTIME();
newTime.wYear = 2015; 
newTime.wMonth = 11;
newTime.wDay = 10;
newTime.wHour = 12;
newTime.wMinute = 0;
newTime.wSecond = 0;
newTime.wMilliseconds = 0;
kernel.SetSystemTime(newTime);
```

For further information have a look into the sources of JNA and on those links
[SetSystemTime Windows function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and 
[SYSTEMTIME structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

An introduction to JNA from 2009. [Simplify Native Code Access with JNA](https://today.java.net/article/2009/11/11/simplify-native-code-access-jna)