# Is it possible to synchronize the system clock through an NTP client in Java?

Tags: java, synchronization, client, ntp

Or it is only to know the offset between the system clock and the server? If my system's clock is different from the server because of the time zone what happens?
thanks

Comment: The OS clock should be maintained by the OS, not by your Java code. If you're doing client/server communication between computers running different timezones, you should make sure both sides agree on the format of date values being transferred, such that no timezone issues occur, e.g. transmit the pure epoch millis (always UTC), or use the new [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) or [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) classes.

Comment: Please be more specific: which client? Setting the system clock is not supported by the Java standard API but there may be platform-specific implementations that can set the system clock. (Although you would need to run Java with elevated privileges and it wouldn't be as accurate as a non-Java implementation without garbage collection and JIT compilation to muck up timings)

Comment: thanks, the client i'm using is apache client: https://commons.apache.org/net/ with NTPUDPClient

Comment: That implementation makes no attempt to update the system time, it just tells you the offset that the NTP server has from your local system clock And personally I don't know of any that implementation that do, but who knows what some commercial vendor may do. Here's a discussion in adjusting the system time from Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203857/how-can-i-set-the-system-time-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't have an API to set system clock directly. This could be done in C/C++ native code called from your Java classes but would require administrative rights to execute.

There are some Java libraries such as [Apache Commons Net](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) project that can compute the clock offset between the local system clock and a remote NTP server. This provides the code to calculate the offset not sync the local clock. To actually sync, recommend to do this using a NTP client/server. There are NTP implementations for nearly all platforms (Windows, Mac, Linux, etc.)

The Java library and NTP services use times based on UTC so time zone settings have no effect.

Example:

```
NTPUDPClient client = new NTPUDPClient();
client.open();
// use host name or IP address of target NTP server
InetAddress hostAddr = InetAddress.getByName("pool.ntp.org");
TimeInfo info = client.getTime(hostAddr);
info.computeDetails(); // compute offset/delay if not already done
Long offsetValue = info.getOffset();
Long delayValue = info.getDelay();
String delay = (delayValue == null) ? "N/A" : delayValue.toString();
String offset = (offsetValue == null) ? "N/A" : offsetValue.toString();

System.out.println(" Roundtrip delay(ms)=" + delay
                + ", clock offset(ms)=" + offset); // offset in ms
client.close();
```

Note that the local clock offset (or time drift) is calculated with respect to the local clock and the NTP server's clock according to this standard NTP equation.

```
LocalClockOffset = ((ReceiveTimestamp - OriginateTimestamp) +
                             (TransmitTimestamp - DestinationTimestamp)) / 2
```

Comment: I know this post is old but would you explain the ReceiveTimestamp, OriginateTimeSatamp, TransmitTImeStamp, and DestinationTimestamp.  I think I understand all except DestinationTimestamp.

Comment: NTP timestamps are described in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65549802/what-time-from-an-ntp-time-server-should-be-used-to-set-my-clock/65588300#65588300)