# How to move system date time in spring boot for testing scheduler scenario?

Tags: java, spring-boot, automated-tests, scheduler, systemtime

In our scheduler application, we are using `quartz scheduler` with `Spring Boot scheduler` which reads `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Spring boot version is `1.3.5`.

We are able to test scenarios like weekly, monthly, yearly by creating `cron` expression w.r.t current date time. And we are trying to simulate some situation where we will change the `current system time` for future and simulate few scenarios.

I know `quartz scheduler` is well tested and no need to test how it will behave in future. Still, if someone has implemented/tested with similar approach, and can share knowledge it will be a great help.

Comment: It's a native method, it receives time from the OS. Try chaning time on the test server/VM.

Comment: Thanks llya... But I want to automate my test....Do you know how to change OS time while starting up the my spring application?

Comment: Look at this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203857/how-can-i-set-the-system-time-in-java - try the ClassLoader trick to set system time.